# Incorrect specification (typo?) of a for loop in pash

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, slurm

I can't seem to find out a way to debug this for loop in bash. It is not a language I regularly use, I am just running an R-Script. I have created my jobs and stored them in a folder (jobs_test). but somehow nothing happens once I enter the command.

This is what I was given originally (jobs_test is the folder and I want to execute all jobs files)

`for i in jobs_test/*.job do sbatch$i; done`
 `for i in jobs_test/*.job do sbatch$i done`
 `for i in jobs_test/*.job do sbatch i; done`
 `for i in jobs_test/*.job do sbatch i done`

For all of these variations I just end up with a prompt ">" and nothing else. If I enter code on the prompt line I get an error like
 `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct version is

```
for i in jobs_test/*.job ; do sbatch "$i"; done
```

Note the semi-colon before the `do`, and the space between `sbatch`and `$i`. Also, adding quotes around `$i` is preferable though not necessary if the script names do not contain spaces, etc.